# How to find the max value between two indices in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like:

```
  | number | dummy
------------------
0 | 1      | 45
1 | 5      | 435
2 | 10     | 112
3 | 7
4 | 8
5 | 9
```

How do I find the max value between index 2 and 4 under column 'number' which in this case is 10.

Comment: `df.iloc[2:5,0].max()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using index labels between 2 and 4 use `loc`:

```
df.loc[2:4, 'number'].max()
```

Output:

```
10
```

If using index integer positions 2nd through the 4th labels, then use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[2:5, df.columns.get_loc('number')].max()
```

*Note: you must use `get_loc` to get the integer position of the column 'number'*

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: Excelent Solution @Scott Boston +1.

Comment: @pygo Thank you.  I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Even can be used:

```
>>> df.iloc[2:4,:].loc[:,'number'].max()
10
```

Comment: looks bit complex @Karn Kumar. Could you please explain why you have used the dot in daisy chain parttern